# Making an AER style reference

Tags: overleaf

I’m sorry for the vague question, and for no MWE on this.
I want to include AER style references in my thesis on Overleaf, but I haven’t been able to find a resource that goes through the process step-by-step. I’m an absolute LaTeX beginner and it’s been overwhelming getting this done. Could you kindly help? I’d be indebted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you familiar with (a) BibTeX and (b) the [aer](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/economic) bibliography style?

Comment: I don’t know which particular files to load - aer.bst, aer.sty and what not. I made a .bib file and tried to follow some generic instructions, but it didn’t render the references in the AER style.

Comment: Do you have an exact requirement, or do you simply want some author-year style?

Comment: I wanted the American Economic Review style that Mico has shown below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what the OP is struggling with -- how to set up bibliographic entries in the .bib file, how to specify a desired bibliography style, how to execute `\cite` commands, and/or how to run a sequence of `latex` and `bibtex` commands? I hope it's not "all of the above"; in that case, the OP should be much more specific as to the nature of the stumbling blocks they are encountering.

Assuming the main tex file (see below) is called `main.tex` and the bib file is called `mybib.bib`, and assuming there are no syntax errors in either of these two files, running

```
latex main
bibtex main
latex main
latex main
```

in sequence should produce the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

% Create a sample bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{ab:3001,
   author = "Anne Author and Brenda Butler",
   title  = "Thoughts",
   year   = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aer} % 'aer.bst' should be part of all TeX distributions

\begin{document}
\cite{ab:3001} % create a citation call-out
\bibliography{mybib} % inform BibTeX which bib file(s) to use
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help Mico. Unfortunately, I needed help on all fronts. My thesis has 5 chapters, and I wanted to add citations to them on their individual .tex files. The method above works when I do all of this on the master.tex file, but when I do it on the individual chapters, it doesn’t work. Also, when I have my bib entry in a separate .bib file, it doesn’t work. Could you please tell me how to solve that?

Comment: Your method works perfectly when I do all of this in my master.tex file. But to be clear, I want to have:
1. One mybib.bib file with all my references
2. I want to use the \cite{} command across all chapters.
3. One consolidated references section at the end of the document, where I include \bibliography{mybib}.
Currently I am being shown the following error: “Package natbib Warning: Citation `ab:3001' on page 1 undefined on input line 2.” I have checked all the spellings for the keys, and they are correct. How can I get this done?

Comment: @grumpyeconomist - About the `natbib` warning message: It very much sounds like you haven't run BibTeX correctly (followed by two more LaTeX runs). Judging by some of your other comments, setting `aer` as the operative bibliography style would seem to be the least of your worries.  Since you've so far given at best a highly impressionistic sketch of your document structure, may I suggest that you post a *new query* in which you (a) take more time to clarify your document structure and (b) ask a more specific question as to what you need to do in order to generate a useful bibliography?